# How do I remove the day from the Chrome OS taskbar?

Tags: taskbar, google-chrome-os

A recent update to Chrome OS added the day of the week in the taskbar, making the time smaller.

Is there way to remove the day from the clock in the taskbar? I want the clock back to its original size.

Comment: What version of chromeOS? if you type: chrome://version you will be able to see it.